# Syncing daemonset

Tags: kubernetes, synchronization, daemonset

Let's say I have a daemonset running in my k8s cluster, and each pod created by the daemonset creates and writes to a directory on the node where it's running. Is there a way to automatically sync the folders with one in the masters? Given I have a multi-master cluster.

Comment: What is the use case here? And what are the constraints? Because the method may depend on the usecase.

Comment: I'm using Fluent Bit to collect logs of applications that are running in K8S clusters. Fluent bit is running as a daemonset, so it's creating a file for every pod running in every node where an application may be running. I've developed a script that filters the log files to the format I need, but instead of running inside every node, I'd like to centralize the log files inside one of the master nodes so that I can run my script once instead of:
1. Accessing every node from the master
2. Running the script
3. Returning the result to the master

Comment: Have you considered using [forward plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/forward)? From docs: `"The out_forward Buffered Output plugin forwards events to other fluentd nodes"`. Or [HA config](https://docs.fluentd.org/deployment/high-availability)?

Comment: I'm going to use HTTP output as it seems the most convenient solution. My only question is, can I limit fluent bit to only return the log for the last 24 hours for e.g? because for now it's sending the ENTIRE pod log inside the request's body, and it will be a lot to handle in the future..

Answer (score 0):

You can have a persistent volume that has `ReadWriteMany` access mode so that all daemonsets can share the same set of data between them.

A simple example is here: http://snippi.com/s/qpge73r

Edit: as @matt commented few drivers support that as here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes

Comment: But not all Drivers support it. Check [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) for a list of drivers that support ReadWriteMany

Comment: maybe a bucket would help if your storage is objects?